# not able to get value from angular.forEach function,flagvalue not getting,Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

This is my controller js, Here i am not able to get value from angular.forEach function, flagvalue not getting, Why?? Scope of flagvalue is end when foreach function ends??is that so??

```
var foreach = angular.module('foreach',[]);
  foreach.controller ('carcontroller', function($scope){
    alert("inn");
    $scope.carname = [{name:'polo'},{name:'BMW'},{name:'Audi'},{name:'Suzuki'}];
    var array = $scope.carname;
    $scope.addcar = function(){
      alert(" innn");
      var currentcarname = $scope.carname;
      alert(currentmoviename);
      angular.forEach($scope.carname,function(refer){   
        alert("in foreach loop");
        var flagvalue;
        alert(flagvalue);
        if(currentcarname.toLowerCase() == refer.name.toLowerCase()){
          alert("in foreach loop - if");
          flagvalue = true;
          return true;
        }
        alert(flagvalue);
        return true;
      });

      if(!flagvalue) {
        alert("in if again");   
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Your variable flagvalue is locally scoped to the function within the angular.forEach call.. This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @doog abides yep....thanx man:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the flag outside the forEach Loop.

```
 var  flagvalue;  
 angular.forEach($scope.carname, function(    refer    )
  {  
      if(currentcarname.toLowerCase() == refer.name.toLowerCase())
         {
           flagvalue    =   true;
            return    true;
         }
       return    true;

});
```

Comment: Thanx Divya:)its working now....can you explain, it will help me to get concept clear...is it releated with scope of var??

Comment: @sumitpethkar this is purely a java script concept,when that variable is inside the foreach function it is local to that function and is not available outside the function.this is the very fundamental thing .Check out the link in the above comment.http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/